# Integrate Deepl with Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, deepl

Anyone knows a way to use Deepl translator inside Google Sheets, similar to the `=GOOGLETRANSLATE` formula?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a simple way. Because Google owns both Sheets and Translate, they were able to set up a simple integration between them.

DeepL has an [API](https://www.deepl.com/en/docs-api/), and a free subscription up to half a million characters per month. The API is not too complicated, judging by [this example](https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/translating-text/request/#example), but you'll need Google Apps Scripts to perform such an HTTP call. So you definitely need to do some JavaScript programming.

Comment: Thanks! I found [this add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/deepl_addon_for_spreadsheets/848993183891), which, however, I assume requires a paid subscription for the API, too?

Answer (score 3):

There is a free API from DeepL, you just need to create an account for it.

Building on @Glorfindel's comment, here is a working Google App Script:

```
function DEEPL(text, sourceLang, targetLang) {
  if (text == "") {
    return "";
  } else if (targetLang == "tr") {
    // Fall back to Google Translate if the language is not supported
    return LanguageApp.translate(text, "en", "tr");
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate?auth_key=REPLACE_ME_WITH_KEY" +
    "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(text) +
    "&target_lang=" + targetLang +
    "&source_lang=" + sourceLang
  );
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  return data["translations"][0]["text"];
}
```

To use the script:

1. Open Google sheets
2. Click on 'Extensions'
3. Click on 'Apps Script'
4. Paste the code
5. Use for example this code in a cell `=DEEPL($A1; "en"; "de")`

If you think of any improvements, feel free to add them.

Comment: Nice! Does it support wrapping inside an arrayformula?

Comment: Working at first, but in 3 days the 500.000 characters quota was finished, which seems to look like the function is called more often than I'd like (guessing each time the Google Sheet is opened, the function is called, so the same translation is repeated over and over).

Comment: Asked about how to try to avoid that issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73682233/apps-script-how-to-call-a-function-only-if-there-is-a-change-instead-of-several

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the Add-Ons marketplace, there is something called Instaglot.  Does pretty much the same thing above.

Only thing is how to trigger the API call only is the source changes.

Answer (score -1):

There's a [Google Sheets addon for DeepL](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/translate_with_deepl/126868842137).

Once you install that, you can use the DEEPL formula in Google Sheets:

```
= DEEPL("Hola", "en", "es")
```

Comment: Nice! Does it support wrapping inside an arrayformula?